# Not able to see WebGoat requests in ZAP proxy

Tags: proxy, zap

I have configured ZAP to port 8090 and also Firefox to 8090, but I am unable to see any requests from WebGoat lessons, whatsoever, except the initial request of http://detectportal.firefox.com. Herewith attached the screenshot of Firefox and ZAP Proxy.

[image: ZAP]

[image: Firefox]

What am I missing here? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at your Firefox proxy settings again.

By default Firefox will set 'No proxy for' 127.0.0.1 and localhost. If you've got WebGoat running locally then you'll want to clear that field so that Firefox proxies local requests through ZAP.

Comment: Also keep in mind that cached requests/responses may not be seen in the history.